# Chain fading in using CSS?

Tags: css

I have a number of divs with the class 'bubble', is it possible to chain fade these in using css? So the first bubble fades in, then the next and so on?

Is it possible to do this once the page loads?

Comment: As you should know by this point... users are expected to include what code they have tried before asking questions. Please update this question with relevant information as to what you have tried or resources you have found.

Comment: Is something stopping you from trying it?

Comment: I dont believe this type of chaining is possible without the use of js. Further more, the implementation is so simple in jQuery that I cant believe you'd be able to find a better solution in CSS.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with an animation delay and a sass loop:

```
.bubble{
    border-radius:100%;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin:1em;
    background:red;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    opacity:0;
    animation: fadeIn 2s ease forwards;
    @for $i from 1 through 10{
        &:nth-of-type(#{$i}){
        animation-delay:#{$i}s;
    }
  }

  @keyframes fadeIn{
      0%:{
          opacity:0;
  }
      100%{
          opacity:1;
  }

}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/jshawl/pen/qdsex)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with [CSS3 keyframe animations](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp).

To create a chaining effect you will need to set a different keyframe rule for each `.bubble` though. You would be much better off using JQuery instead.